# Run synchronous tasks using node.js on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, synchronization, node-ffi

I am using the Node FFI module and am trying to run sync tasks on Windows. I can successfully run a task using the following code.

```
var ffi=require('ffi')
var nativeC = new ffi.Library("Kernel32", {
"WinExec": ["int32", ["string"]]
});

nativeC.WinExec('ls -lrt');
```

I presume this is the way to execute sync tasks, but this code always exits after the 1st 'ls -lrt' command; if I chain a few more commands, they won't work. So, is there a callback function over here, in the FFI module, or another way I can chain commands in node.js on Windows so they run in sync, one after the other.

Comment: [`ls`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls) is not typically available in Windows [outside of PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) (and that doesn't recognize `-lrt` options). Does the command work in `cmd.exe`? For multiple users?

Comment: so, i am using Git bash, so I can use ls, I thought of posting that, so sorry i did not.

Comment: Try `nativeC.WinExec('bash -c "ls -lrt"');`. Even if you're using `bash` to execute the script, [`WinExec()` doesn't seem to use it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687393.aspx) (note its 2nd argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need WinExec to run a windows command. As Jonathan pointed out, ls isn't available.

However, if you want to chain commands you could use async.js and exec like this:

```
var
  async = require('async'); 
  exec = require('child_process').exec,
  commands = [ 'dir /w', 'echo test'];

var executeCommand = function(command, callback){
  exec(command, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    if(err) return callback(err);
    console.log(stdout);
    callback();
  });
};

async.eachSeries(commands, executeCommand, function(err){
  console.log('error: ' + err);
});
```